# PyQt5 QtWebEngineWidgets stopped working after pyqt5 and sip reinstall

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

screenshot of resulting window - WebEngineview is blank

[image]

I reinstalled pyqt5 and sip yesterday to help with issues with pyinstaller. Since then QtWebEngineWidgets which was working well previously has stopped responding. Below is a simple snippet that was working before.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class Ui_Force(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
      MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
      MainWindow.resize(1200, 900)
      MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
      MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(15, 45, 80);\n"
     "QPushButton { color: red }\n"
     "QLineEdit { color: red }\n"
     "QComboBox { color: red }\n""")
     `MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
      MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
      MainWindow.setDockNestingEnabled(True)
      self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
      self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

      self.groupBox_4 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
      self.groupBox_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 1000, 750))
      self.groupBox_4.setObjectName("groupBox_4")
      self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView(self.groupBox_4)
      self.webEngineView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 900, 700))
      self.webEngineView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
      self.webEngineView.setObjectName("webEngineView")
      MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

      self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
      QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
       _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
       MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Project Network"))
       self.groupBox_4.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "webpage"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Force()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What version of python, pyqt5 and pyinstaller do you use and how do you install/update it?

Comment: I used pip: pip install pyqt5; pip install sip, versions are: PyQt5                           5.14.0             
PyQt5-sip                          12.7.0 PyInstaller                        3.5     The code does not display the web page even if I launch it from python3. It was fine before.

Comment: what is the error message? .... install pyqtwebengine: `pip install pyqtwebengine`

Comment: I don't get a error message. The window shows but the web view in the window is blank. And did do: pip install pyqtwebengine    "pyqtwebengine in /Users/.../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (5.14.0)" -Thanks

Comment: You could show a picture of what you get.

Comment: I recommend: Do not use anaconda since I have seen several bugs caused by that environment. Create a virtualenv and only install pyqt5, pyqtwebengine and pyinstaller and then create the executable. On the other hand, how do you run pyinstaller? What files (.dlls, .so, etc) next to the executable?

Comment: Not sure how to upload a picture. But essentially it is a blank window. the space for the weengineview just flashes twice and goes blank

Comment: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I just did pyinstaller filename-py -F and have tried other combinations. But the problem occurs even before running pyinstaller. When I run the the .py file from python

Comment: If your code worked before updating PyQt5 (just updated to 5.14 yesterday) then pyinstaller probably has a bug that the new version of PyQt5 cannot handle.

Comment: Added the screenshot -  thanks.

Comment: If your code worked before updating PyQt5 (just updated to 5.14 yesterday) then pyinstaller probably has a bug that the new version of PyQt5 cannot handle. My recommendation: Use pyqt5 5.13.2 with python 3.7, or better use fbs